# Name specification to use when starting a gen_server in erlang by {via,RegMod,ViaName}

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

In erlang gen_server, [it says](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#type-server_name)

```
{via,RegMod,ViaName}

Register the gen_server process with the registry represented by RegMod. 
The RegMod callback is to export the functions register_name/2, unregister_name/1,
 whereis_name/1, and send/2, which are to behave like the corresponding functions in global. 
Thus, {via,global,GlobalName} is a valid reference equivalent to {global,GlobalName}.
```

But I cannot find any example about it, can anyone show an example about `{via,RegMod,ViaName}`?